# Mocking node dependency for Typescript with Mocha / Sinon

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, typescript, mocha.js, sinon

I have a class which controls an audio receiver using an external library `marantz-avr`:

```
let AVReceiver = require('marantz-avr');

class MarantzPlugin {

    hardwareInstance;

    constructor(pluginConfiguration) {
        const receiver = new AVReceiver(pluginConfiguration.settings.ip);
        this.hardwareInstance = receiver;
    }

    turnPowerOn() {
        this.hardwareInstance.setPowerState('on').then(res => res, error => console.error(error));
    }

}

export default MarantzPlugin;
```

I want to unit test this class. In order to do so I have to mock the `marantz-avr` library since this library only works when an actual receiver is found on the provided ip address.

In the test below I mock the `marantz-avr`, however the MarantzPlugin still uses the original `AVReceiver` instead of the mocked one.

```
import { suite, test, slow, timeout } from 'mocha-typescript';
import * as mocha from 'mocha';
import * as assert from 'assert';
import * as sinon from 'sinon';
import * as should from 'should';

import MarantzPlugin from './';
let AVReceiver = require('marantz-avr');

@suite
class MarantzPluginTest {

    public create() {

        before(() => {
            sinon.stub(AVReceiver.prototype, 'AVReceiver').callsFake(() => {

                return {
                    setPowerState: () => {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        let marantz = new MarantzPlugin({
            id: 'MARANTZ',
            settings: {
                ip: '192.168.178.2',
            }
        });

        marantz.setPowerState('on');

    }

}
```

I've looked into http://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/ but when implemented it gave me `Error: Cannot find module 'marantz-avr'`

Does anyone see what I am missing here, or perhaps have a better way to unit test these kind of classes?

Comment: Try stubbing before you import your plugin class. Js modules that export a function are a notorious pain

Comment: So import MarantzPlugin just the line before `let marantz = new MarantzPlugin({`?

Comment: Move sinon.stub above import MarantzPlugin

Comment: Unfortunately then I get "Cannot stub non-existent own property AVReceiver"

Comment: It said that  `sinon.stub(AVReceiver.prototype, 'AVReceiver')` AVReceiver method is not existed in your class